# Node & Express: Add parameters to redirect on Back button press

Tags: node.js, express

I d like to redirect to the previous page with some extra parameters when back button is pressed.

e.g. : `req.query.cleanForm = 'true';`

So that i know that I should clean the form, ignore state...etc

How can I achieve this node express?

*A bit more context:* 
Actually, what i have is a paginated quiz session. Upon completion of this quiz, the user may click on 'Back'. In that case, i want the user to restart the whole quiz process and not just go back to the last question.

Comment: what do you mean with extra parameters?

Comment: @JoseOsorio updated.

Comment: You can get some parameters from the header, like 'Referer' `req.header('Referer')`. Then an if condition can do the trick of redirecting to the root in case the referer for page 2 is page 3.